# How to convert DapperRow with multiple objects into a usable Dictionary?

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper, serenity-platform

For reference I'm using the Serenity application template.

I have the following code

```
var query = new SqlQuery();
        query.From("TenantData")
            .Select("ItemData")
            .Select("ItemType")
            .Where(new Criteria("TenantID") == userDefinition.TenantId);

        using (var connection = sqlConnections.NewByKey("Default"))
        {
            var data = connection.Query(query);
        }
```

The data returned looks like {{DapperRow, ItemData = '2342342wef', ItemType = 'test'}}

What I'm struggling with is how to convert this into a dictionary (ItemData being the key, ItemType being the value).

I've tried a select but it doesn't seem to be supported so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work.

```
var data = connection.Query(query);

var d = data.ToDictionary(row => (string)row.itemdata, row => (string)row.itemtype);
```

Make sure you add the `using System.Linq;` at the top. `ToDictionary()` is an extension method.